# Django: Display an expression-generated field in the admin based on params not in the model

Tags: python, django

Versions: Django 1.5.4, Python 2.7.x, MySQL, on Ubuntu

I have a time-keeping system. Every Project has many Users, and all Users have been Projects. When these users submit their hours, they select the project and an integer number of hours.

I want the projects panel in the admin to display the total number of Hours each User has spent on the project. I'm able to add a ref to Hours to Project, but then it adds Hours as a required field to the Project model.

I am unsure of how to modify my Project model to show the number of hours each User has spent on a project.

The Models:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    client = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    campaign_start_date = models.DateField()
    hours = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    hours = models.IntegerField(default=0) 

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
    def project_members(self):
        return ', '.join([p.username for p in self.members.all()])

class Hour(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    hour = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    date = models.DateField()
    project = models.ManyToManyField(Project, related_name="hourquery+")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.user) + ' ' + str(self.date)

    def project_names(self):
        return ', '.join([p.name for p in self.project.all()])
```

Comment: So, what is the problem you are facing ? clearly, you have `hours = models.IntegerField(default=0)` which is a non-nullable field

Comment: @karthikr I am unsure of how to modify my Project model to show the number of hours each User has spent on a project.

Comment: You mean `Hour.hour` instead of `Project.hour` ?

Comment: @karthikr No, I want to pass a reference from Hour.hour to Project to computer how many hours total each User has spent on the Project.

Comment: First off, you probably don't want a `ManyToManyField` from `Hour` to `Project`, unless a given `Hour` entry can be assigned to multiple products. Secondly, you are ending your `related_name` argument with a `+`, which tells Django not to create exactly the kind of reverse relationship you're trying to follow. If you use the default related name, `some_project.hour_set.aggregate(Sum('hour'))` should be what you're looking for. You have to import `Sum` from django.db.models first, of course.

Comment: Hi Peter, thank you for this. You're absolutely right about Hour not being a M2M relationship with Project. Let me refactor my models based on your comment and see if I can achieve the data flow I'm looking for.

Comment: Actually, that doesn't limit it by user - for that you'd use a `values=("user")` clause to group `Hour` rows by user, and then `annotate` instead of `aggregate`. Or filter to a specific user before aggregating.

Comment: Aggregate did seem like a total summation to me without filtering, but I wanted to follow your logic through first. Let me try the values-("user") method.